# Identifying unknown coordinates/coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, chile

I have a set of data for the country of Chile which has geospatial information in the form of `'XX0000X'` where `X` is a letter and `0` is a number. I have not been able to figure out what these coordinates are in my googling.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Example:

**GEOREF**

```
GT5346D
GL9366D
GK7748C
HD3342D
IB7926D
IB7926D
ZQ6108B
IB7932D
GL9366D
GL9366D
YG8782A
GB1982B
YG8374B
DE1302A
GL9368C
ZM5324B
```

Comment: If you type "coordinate system GeoRef" in any search engine, the first result will be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geographic_Reference_System. That should be a good starting point.

Comment: these could refer to a custom grid or some parcel references, could you tell us more about the data (what kind of data this is, should they plot to point or polygons, where did you get it....), the best way to really find would be to identify the data producer and ask them

Comment: I tried to convert one of the strings into lat/lon by assuming it was MGRS. That included prefixing with 18 or 19 plus the letter for a latitude band, but it didn't convert. It's likely a local map reference with a map sheet using a 2 letter prefix or multiple ones per sheet, xx and yy for part of the coordinate and ABCD to subdivide that into quarters. I looked at IGM's 1:50k but didn't see any letter references and the 1:25k is only available to customers.